# Kendo Refresh (DropDownList.refresh()) not working ERROR Not define

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, kendo-ui

Im trying to refresh the Drop Down List after another DropDownList is Change But the Refresh() method is Undefined Error Is Promoting.There For I Tried the Read the DataSource again   and it shows it loading but the data is still the same.Help to Solve this Issue please.

Code:

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
   custCode = $("#DropDownList1").val();

   $("#titles").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read(); //shows list Loading But Same Data Is present .
   $("#titles").data("kendoDropDownList").refresh(); //NOT Working 

});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1- Try adding `cache: false` to disable the cache in Kendo DropDownList's datasource read property:

```
read: {
    url: <<"url">>,
    cache: false
}
```

2- Then call `read()`,

```
$("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: Hi it not working for me.my data comes the problem is the kendoDropDownList shows the old data and the refresh method it undefined for some reason.

Comment: Note:My Drop-down is not filled by a Read . its filled by in form load.

Comment: Sorry Something Wrong with my Code :P

Answer (score 9):

For me just this line did the job:

`$("#myDropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();`

Answer (score 2):

You might find passing parameters to the ".data()" of the dataSource useful.

Example:

```
var myDataSource={bookId: 10, Name: "Kendo"}
$("#titles").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(myDataSource);
```

However, you could also try the [cascadingFrom](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist) attribute of the DropDownList when you want to update one DropDownList based on the selection of another DropDownList

//Houdini

Answer (score 0):

on your read url add '?myDate=' + new Date(). This will refresh the data. Without it (unless you have meta tags to prevent caching) it will give you that data it has already read.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I commented the line

```
//cascadeFrom: "dropdown1_id"
```

on the second kendo dropdown and it worked, for some reason it was messing with the data source updates.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Kendo dropdownlist has changed.  Now the answer is:

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: my_new_json_list
    });
    var dropdownlist = $("#products").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Reference: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/setdatasource