# Issue updating Kendo DropDownList with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

I've got a Kendo DropDownList that I want to update/refresh via a javascript function. Using FireFox and Chrome, it works fine but with Internet Explorer, it doesn't update anything.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("myDDL")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 320px" })
    .DataTextField("Description")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("fillDDL", "ControllerName");
        });
    })
)
```

The javascript function:

```
function refreshForm() {
    $("#myDDL").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
}
```

And also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132939/kendo-refresh-dropdownlist-refresh-not-working-error-not-define) but no luck.

I am testing with Internet Explorer 11.

Any help?

**Edit**

This is the generated Javascript code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#myDDL").kendoDropDownList({
        "dataSource": {
             "transport": {
                 "read": {
                     "url": "/ControllerName/fillDDL"
                 },
                 "prefix": ""
             },
             "schema": {
                 "errors": "Errors"
             }
         },
         "dataTextField": "Description",
         "dataValueField": "Id"
     });
});
```

Comment: Your first function that calls `dataSource.read` looks correct. Does it make a server request to load new data when it is called? Could you include the generated JavaScript from the MVC helper?

Comment: Other than the ID being different (`concessions` vs `myDDL`) your code looks correct. Does your call to `dataSource.read()` cause a request to the server with the URL "/ControllerName/fillDDL"?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, how can I know that?

Comment: Browser dev tools (usually, press F12, then go to the "Network" tab, but may vary by browser). For Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network and for IE11: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, I just found the answer and posted it. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution and I'm posting it so it helps others who may face the same problem.

Now I have

```
read.Action("fillDDL", "ControllerName").Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
```

instead of

```
read.Action("fillDDL", "ControllerName");
```

Adding this bit of code now allows the DropDownList to be refreshed, even when using Internet Explorer.